# OS X Server leaves some unwanted open ports after removal

Tags: terminal, server.app, launchd, macos

I am currently running OS X Version 10.9.5 (Mavericks).
In the past I installed OS X server and had to sign some certificates so that users could authenticate with the VPN function (which is what I mostly used the server for), and later I removed OS X server from the OS.

However, upon further inspection some months later, I noticed that there were still traces of those certificates and/or services were still running unnoticed. I did an nmap scan against my machine to reassure myself that my observations were indeed correct. And correct they were. Here's the scan:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=B3vbG8q6

So I looked around the web for some answers... came across a few that said I should remove the certificates from my Keychain Access, which I tried. That didn't work, got the same exact nmap scan result.

Then I thought that maybe there was a process (or processes) running that related to those open ports. In terminal I did:

> sudo lsof -i :625

and

> sudo lsof -i :636

and same with ports 749 and 3659 to get the processes that were associated with them.

Then I did:

> sudo kill -9 PID

but it became apparent that those were persistent processes after conducting another nmap scan and further *lsof -i* commands, only to find myself looking at different numbers under **PID** :/

My desired result is for the mmap scan to not show any traces of there being a server on my system, or even a server installed in the past. I've looked everywhere and the very few clues that I've found didn't get me what I need.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the Server.app (3.2.2) for 10.9 Mavericks isn't enough. You also have to unload several launch daemons.

By comparing all "System LaunchDaemons" in a basic Server.app install and an LDAP/VPN environment in two different VMs I assume that the following system launch daemons have to be unloaded permanently:

```
org.openldap.slapd
com.apple.xscertd-helper
com.apple.xscertd
com.apple.xscertadmin
com.apple.PasswordService
com.apple.odproxyd
org.apache.httpd
```

The most comfortable tool to do this is probably [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/).

To completely remove all files and folders created by installing, launching and configuring Server.app I have to compile a list of files and folders to delete first (which will take some time).

Here is a list of newly created files and folders after installing and configuring OpenLDAP and VPN in Server.app (3.2.2):

```
/System/Applications/Server.app/
/System/Applications/Workgroup Manager.app/
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serverd.plist
/System/Library/Logs/EventMonitor/
/System/Library/Logs/EventMonitor/EventMonitor.error.log
/System/Library/Logs/Mail/
/System/Library/Logs/PasswordService/
/System/Library/Logs/PostgreSQL/
/System/Library/Logs/ProfileManager/
/System/Library/Logs/radiusconfig.log
/System/Library/Logs/Server
/System/Library/Logs/ServerSetup.log
/System/Library/Logs/Setup.log
/System/Library/Logs/slapconfig.log
/System/Library/Logs/WebDAVSharing.log
/System/Library/Logs/WebServer
/System/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AccountsConfigServer.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/com.apple.openldap.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/com.apple.serverd.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_accounts.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_info.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgrd.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/edu.mit.Kerberos.kadmind.launchd
/System/Library/Preferences/edu.mit.Kerberos.krb5kdc.launchd
/System/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/
/System/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/DynamicData/…………….plist
/System/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/DynamicData/LDAPv3/
/System/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount.plist
/System/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.RemoteAccessServers.plist
/System/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd
/System/Library/Security/Trust Settings/
/System/Library/Server/
/System/private/etc/af.plist
/System/private/etc/asl/com.apple.server.asl
/System/private/etc/bootpd.plist
/System/private/etc/certificates/Server Fallback SSL Certificate… #several
/System/private/etc/certificates/Code Signing Certificate… #several
/System/private/etc/certificates/fqdn.…………….cert.pem
/System/private/etc/certificates/fqdn.…………….chain.pem
/System/private/etc/certificates/fqdn.…………….concat.pem
/System/private/etc/certificates/fqdn.…………….key.pem
/System/private/etc/emond.d/state/
/System/private/etc/krb5.conf
/System/private/etc/newsyslog.d/com.apple.devicemgr.conf
/System/private/etc/newsyslog.d/com.apple.mailservices.conf
/System/private/etc/newsyslog.d/servermgr_calendar_log.conf
/System/private/etc/openldap/rootDSE.ldif
/System/private/etc/openldap/slapd_macosxserver.conf
/System/private/etc/openldap/slapd.conf
/System/private/etc/openldap/slapd.d.backup/
/System/private/etc/openldap/slapd.d/
/System/private/etc/paths.d/com.apple.server
/System/private/etc/pear.conf
/System/private/etc/php.ini
/System/private/etc/php.ini-5.4-previous
/System/private/etc/postfix/aliases.desktop
/System/private/etc/rc.server
/System/private/etc/rc.server.firewall
/System/private/tftpboot/NetBoot/
/System/private/var/db/.ServerSetupDone
/System/private/var/db/af/
/System/private/var/db/BootCaches/……………/app.com.apple.Server.v3.playlist
/System/private/var/db/dovecot.fts.update/
/System/private/var/db/emondClients/com.apple.server
/System/private/var/db/krb5kdc/
/System/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.220/
/System/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.70/
/System/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.93/
/System/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.94/
/System/private/var/db/net-snmp/
/System/private/var/db/ntp-kod
/System/private/var/db/openldap/authdata/
/System/private/var/db/openldap/replication/
/System/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.WorkgroupManager.bom
/System/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.WorkgroupManager.plist
/System/private/var/db/ServerPerfLogClients/com.apple.server
/System/private/var/db/systemstats/…………….boot.events.….stats
/System/private/var/db/systemstats/…………….powerd.events.….stats
/System/private/var/db/systemstats/…………….system_events.events.….stats
/System/private/var/db/systemstats/…………….system_events.periodic.….stats
/System/private/var/dovecot/
/System/private/var/folders/zz/
/System/private/var/log/apache2/accept.lock.710
/System/private/var/log/apache2/access_log
/System/private/var/log/apache2/error_log
/System/private/var/log/apache2/rewrite.lock
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/agent.log
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/certupdate.log
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/migration.log
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/postgresql/
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/postgresql/postgresql_1.log
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/servermgr_calendar.log
/System/private/var/log/caldavd/xpg_ctl.log
/System/private/var/log/com.apple.launchd.peruser.220/
/System/private/var/log/com.apple.launchd.peruser.70/
/System/private/var/log/com.apple.launchd.peruser.93/
/System/private/var/log/com.apple.launchd.peruser.94/
/System/private/var/log/com.apple.launchd/…………….launchd.events.….stats
/System/private/var/log/devicemgr
/System/private/var/log/eventmonitor/
/System/private/var/log/eventmonitor/StoreData
/System/private/var/log/getsslpassphrase.log
/System/private/var/log/krb5kdc/
/System/private/var/log/localemanager.log
/System/private/var/log/mail.log
/System/private/var/log/ppp/vpnd.log
/System/private/var/log/radius/
/System/private/var/log/servermgrd.log
/System/private/var/log/slapd.log
/System/private/var/log/swupd/
/System/private/var/log/xscertd.log
/System/private/var/pgsql_socket/
/System/private/var/run/caldavd/
/System/private/var/run/httpd.pid
/System/private/var/run/jabberd/
/System/private/var/run/kadmind.pid
/System/private/var/run/kdc.pid
/System/private/var/run/kpasswdd.pid
/System/private/var/run/ldapi
/System/private/var/run/passwordserver
/System/private/var/run/racoon.pid
/System/private/var/run/racoon/
/System/private/var/run/servermgrd.pid
/System/private/var/run/slapd.args
/System/private/var/run/slapd.pid
/System/private/var/run/vpnd-L2TP.pid
/System/private/var/servermgrd/
/System/Users/username/Library/Caches/com.apple.Server.v3/
/System/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/
/System/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.serveralertproxy.plist
/System/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Server.v3.plist
/System/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ServerAssistant.plist
/System/usr/bin/pear
/System/usr/bin/peardev
/System/usr/bin/pecl
/System/usr/lib/php/.channels/
/System/usr/lib/php/.depdb
/System/usr/lib/php/.depdblock
/System/usr/lib/php/.filemap
/System/usr/lib/php/.lock
/System/usr/lib/php/.registry/
/System/usr/lib/php/Archive/
/System/usr/lib/php/Console/
/System/usr/lib/php/data/
/System/usr/lib/php/doc/
/System/usr/lib/php/OS/
/System/usr/lib/php/PEAR.php
/System/usr/lib/php/PEAR/
/System/usr/lib/php/pearcmd.php
/System/usr/lib/php/peclcmd.php
/System/usr/lib/php/Structures/
/System/usr/lib/php/System.php
/System/usr/lib/php/test/
/System/usr/lib/php/XML/
/System/usr/lib/sasl2/openldap/digestmd5WebDAV.la
/System/usr/lib/sasl2/openldap/digestmd5WebDAV.so
/System/usr/lib/sasl2/openldap/libcrammd5.2.so
/System/usr/lib/sasl2/openldap/libcrammd5.la
/System/usr/lib/sasl2/openldap/libdigestmd5.2.so
/System/usr/lib/sasl2/openldap/libdigestmd5.la
```

keys:

```
/: if a line ends with a / the whole folder or app and its content is newly created  
username: your username  
……………: some arbitrary UUID or digits/letters > 8
…: some arbitrary digits/letters < 8
fqdn: full qualified domain name
```

Despite the greatest care taken in the creation of this list I cannot guarantee its accuracy. Delete those files at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you, that led me in the right direction. I've found all of the launch daemons that you listed above and removed them manually using Terminal (LaunchControl was malfunctioning severely, dk why). Then I used _launchctl_ _list_ | _grep_ _Kerberos_ to find and eliminate the Kerberos 'safe' authentication protocol. Now my nmap results are pleasing. If there's any launchd that I might have forgotten to remove (or any extra ones), please inform me if possible. Thank you